# Android Artoolkit 3d model offset from marker

Tags: android, augmented-reality, artoolkit, android-augmented-reality

I'm using Artoolkit AR SDK for Android and i have a problem. When marker is in center of screen, then model is on marker.
[image: Correct]

But when marker moving from center of screen, 3d model shifted from marker.
[image: Incorrect]

I can't understand where the mistake.

Comment: hi @Rusian khuako i am new to AR. Please tell me how to add bitmap texture in ARToolkit Sample code . Need  your help

Comment: hi @NipunGogia you must use simple openGl example with cube, swap cube with squad and apply texture to this squad, this is very useful info about applying textures: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/Android_3D.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a FOV problem. Try using a different resolution on the camera.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's the problem!

Comment: Glad you solved it. For some reason, ARToolkit has problems calculating the FOV on certain resolutions / aspect ratios, very dependent on the phone.